# recvfrom api in socket program for linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp

```
int acceptSocket;
char buf[100];
long sentbytes;
socklen_t len;
int port = 18227;

int CreateSocket()
{
    long rc;
    struct sockaddr_in addr, client;

       // Socket creation for UDP
       acceptSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

       if(acceptSocket==-1)
       {
         printf("Failure: socket creation is failed, failure code\n");
         return 1;
       }
       else
       {
         printf("Socket started!\n");
       }

     memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
     addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
     addr.sin_port=htons(port);
     addr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
     rc=bind(acceptSocket,(struct sockaddr*)&addr,sizeof(addr));

     if(rc== -1)
     {
       printf("Failure: listen, failure code:\n");
       return 1;
     }
     else
     {
       printf("Socket an port %d \n",port);
     }

     while(rc!=-1)
         {
         len =sizeof(client);
         rc=recvfrom(acceptSocket,buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &client, &len);
         if(rc==0)
         {
           printf("Server has no connection..\n");
           break;
         }
         if(rc==-1)
         {
             printf("something went wrong with data %s", strerror(errno));
           break;
         }

         XcpIp_RxCallback( (uint16) rc, (uint8*) buf, (uint16) port );

            makeTimer("First Timer", &firstTimerID, 2, 2);   //2ms
                makeTimer("Second Timer", &secondTimerID, 10, 10);    //10ms
                makeTimer("Third Timer", &thirdTimerID, 100, 100);  //100ms
          }

       close(acceptSocket);
       return 0;
     }

int main()
{
     Xcp_Initialize();
     CreateSocket();
     return 0;
}

//API for sending the data to the client.
void XcpApp_IpTransmit( uint16 XcpPort,  Xcp_StatePtr8 pBytes, uint16 numBytes )
{
    struct sockaddr_in client;

        if ((long)XcpPort==port){
                sentbytes = sendto(acceptSocket,(char*)pBytes,(long)numBytes,0, (struct sockaddr*)&client, sizeof(client));
        }
        XcpIp_TxCallback(port,(uint16)sentbytes);
}
```

I created a server side program for receiving data from the client and sending the response back to the client. I don't know where is the mistake in the above program, I am able to receive data from the client and the rc value is zer0 in that case. Then I am checking the value of rc and it is coming out of the program. later There is no response back to the client. Client is a tool for sending the data to the specified port and ip address.

what could be the problem and why rc value is zero after the recvfrom api ??
NOTE: Client will be keep on sending the data. Could anyone help me in this ?

Comment: `Client is a tool for sending the data to the specified port and ip address` which tool? is it hercules or any other?

Comment: INCA is the tool!!! my problem is : during debugging : it is coming inside the while loop but the rc value is becoming zero.

Answer (score 0):

According to recvfrom man page

> Upon successful completion, recvfrom() shall return the length of the
>   message in bytes. If no messages are available to be received and the
>   peer has performed an orderly shutdown, recvfrom() shall return 0.
>   Otherwise, the function shall return -1 and set errno to indicate the
>   error.

So i think in your case You get a return value of 0 for `recvfrom()` when the connection was closed by the other host (wether this disconnection was graceful or not doesn't matter)

Also i have updated your code please try it on your end

```
#define BUFLEN 100  //Max length of buffer
#define PORT 18227   //The port on which to listen for incoming data

void die(char *s)
{
    perror(s);
exit(1);
}

int acceptSocket;
char buf[BUFLEN];
long sentbytes;

int CreateSocket()
{
    struct sockaddr_in si_me, si_other, si_other2;

    int s, i, slen = sizeof(si_other) , recv_len;

    //create a UDP socket
    if ((acceptSocket=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1)
    {
        die("socket");
    }

    // zero out the structure
    memset((char *) &si_me, 0, sizeof(si_me));

    si_me.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_me.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    si_me.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    //bind socket to port
    if( bind(acceptSocket , (struct sockaddr*)&si_me, sizeof(si_me) ) == -1)
    {
        die("bind");
    }

    //keep listening for data
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Waiting for data...");
        fflush(stdout);

        //try to receive some data, this is a blocking call
        if ((recv_len = recvfrom(acceptSocket, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen)) == -1)   // read datagram from server socket
        {
            die("recvfrom()");
        }

        //print details of the client/peer and the data received
        printf("Received packet from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(si_other.sin_addr), ntohs(si_other.sin_port));         printf("Data: %s\n" , buf);

        XcpIp_RxCallback( (uint16) rc, (uint8*) buf, (uint16) port );

        makeTimer("First Timer", &firstTimerID, 2, 2);   //2ms
        makeTimer("Second Timer", &secondTimerID, 10, 10);    //10ms
        makeTimer("Third Timer", &thirdTimerID, 100, 100);  //100ms
    }

    close(s);
 }
```

Comment: 'printf("Data: %s\n" , buf);' - will crash, in general, because of the lack of a null terminator.